# Can someone explain to me why my HTML/CSS is not correct but very close ? The Odin Project Flexbox Layout 02

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

```css
type herehtml, body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 16px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  align-items: center
  ;
}

.footer {
  height: 72px;
  background: #eee;
  color: darkmagenta;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color:antiquewhite
  display: flex;
  background: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 400px
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  
  
  
  

}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 32px;
  margin: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
  gap: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: max-content;
  width:300px
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap

width: fit-content;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;

}
.big {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}


.card{
  height: 300px;
  width:auto; 

}
.big {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
      MY AWESOME WEBSITE
    </div>
    <div class="big">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">⭐ - link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">️ - link three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> - link four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit corrupti veritatis minima porro?</div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit ea.</div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

      The Odin Project ❤️
    </div>
```

I got it to look very close but there are a lot of little things that look off. The sidebar text is too tight and my cards are too tall and not laid out properly.

I was instructed to use flex-wrap for the cards but that changes nothing, I struggled enough just to get the 'Holy Grail Layout' itself.

I've looked at the available solution and it is not described.

Comment: So, what would you expect as a result? Would you like the sidebar to fit the size of the text, or would you like the text to fit in the sidebar? What about cards? They don't look too tall to me from a PC, but they actually are from a phone, so would you like a minimum width?

Answer (score 0):

You left only Semicolon in css I have commented Where you left semicolon.
This is your solved code.

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 16px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  align-items: center
  ;
}

.footer {
  height: 72px;
  background: #eee;
  color: darkmagenta;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color:antiquewhite;/* here you leave semicolon*/
  display: flex;
  background: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 400px;/* here you leave semicolon*/
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 16px;

}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 32px;
  margin: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
  gap: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: max-content;
  width:300px
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;/* here you leave semicolon*/
    width: fit-content;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.big {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}


.card{
  height: 300px;
  width:auto; 

}
.big {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        MY AWESOME WEBSITE
      </div>
      <div class="big">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">⭐ - link one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">️ - link three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> - link four</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <div class="container">
  
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit corrupti veritatis minima porro?</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit ea.</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
  
        The Odin Project ❤️
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```